# Order of query execution in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, optimization, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I would like to understand the behavior, that is the evaluation process and order of the following statement.

Starting point, two simple tables as follows:

Table "A":

```
COL_A
-----
    1
    2
    3
    4
```

Table "B":

```
COL_B
-----
    1
    2
    3
    5
```

Statement executed:

```
select a.col_a, b.col_b
from a  left join b
on a.col_a=b.col_b
where b.col_b <> 5;
```

Result:

```
COL_A COL_B
----- -----
    1     1
    2     2
    3     3
```

optimizer 1st execute the where clause and then it will go to left join or vice versa ?

Sorry in advance if the question is silly.

Comment: The optimizer, no matter what it does, is required to preserve the logical meaning of operations. In this case, whatever the optimizer does, the result must be consistent with evaluating the left outer join first, and only then the `where` clause. And, since in the `where` clause you have a condition on the **right** side of the join (not sure where Tim saw "left"), the `where` clause will eliminate all the `outer` rows, causing the join to become an `inner` join, despite your intent. Again, this will be true regardless of how the optimizer may evaluate your query.

Comment: Hi @mathguy,
Below is the access path.

   1 - access("A"."A"="B"."B")
   2 - filter("A"."A"<>5)
   3 - filter("B"."B"<>5)
 is there a way where i can enforce optimizer to 1st evaluate where clause?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I assume you would like the value 4 from the first table to appear in the output? If so, you must **move** the condition on `b.b` - instead of a `where` clause, it should be in the `join` condition, along with `a.a = b.b`.

Comment: _" is there a way where i can enforce optimizer to 1st evaluate where clause?"_   Why would you want to?